# Onclick functionality in Phone gap-Android NOT functioning in android devices with lower versions of android

Tags: html, css, onclick, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I am working in Phone gap- android using cordova 2.1.0 and android 2.2.

My SQLITE PLUGIN- is compatible to cordova-2.1.0.

My onclick functionality works in android devices versions 4,but not working in android devices with lower versions.

I am facing a similar problem with the CSS **position:fixed** that did not work in android devices with lower versions.The alternative I took up was iscroll, but yet to fix it up.

Please guide me for this issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is was because I had called **onload** function of **iscroll in my body tag**. Later when I called my body tag after all my onclick functionalities **it worked!**